# AWS Lambda nodejs upload file to ftp

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I'm using lambda nodejs to upload file to ftp server.

the source code for upload file:

```
const ftp = require('basic-ftp');
const fs = require('fs');

class FTPClient {
    constructor(host = 'localhost', port = 21, username = 'anonymous', password = 'guest', secure = false) {
        this.client = new ftp.Client();
        this.settings = {
            host: host,
            port: port,
            user: username,
            password: password,
            secure: secure
        };
    }

    upload(sourcePath, remotePath) {
        let self = this;
        (async () => {
            try {
                let access = await self.client.access(self.settings);
                let upload = await self.client.upload(fs.createReadStream(sourcePath), remotePath);
            } catch(err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            self.client.close();
        })();
    }

    close() {
        this.client.close();
    }
}

module.exports = FTPClient;
```

the index.js file:

```
const createCsvWriter = require('csv-writer').createObjectCsvWriter;
const ftp = require('./upload');
const request = require('request');

let doRequest = async (url) => {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        request(url, function (error, res, body) {
            if (!error && res.statusCode == 200) {
                resolve(body);
            } else {
                reject(error);
            }
        });
    });
}


let createFile = async (data) => {
    let fileName = 'fileName.csv';

    const csvWriter = createCsvWriter({
        path: '/tmp/fileName.csv',
        header: [
            { id: 'date', title: 'Date' },
            { id: 'mac_address', title: 'MAC_Address' },
            { id: 'enter', title: 'Enter' }
        ]
    });

    await csvWriter.writeRecords(data);

    const client = new ftp('ftphost', 21, 'ftp_username', 'ftp_password');

    await client.upload('/tmp/fileName.csv', fileName);
}

exports.handler = async (event, s3FileStreamContent) => {

    let dataExcel = [];
    let url = 'http://example.com/apiUrl';//only for example

    let res = await doRequest(url);
    let data = JSON.parse(res).data;


    dataExcel.push({
        date: data.date,
        mac_address: data.mac,
        enter: data.enter
    });

    createFile(data);
};
```

The log after run:

> Response:
>
> null
>
> Request ID:
>
> "9c8e1701-ad54-42eb-8dc6-bbed77bc9b41"
>
> Function Logs:
>
> START RequestId: 9c8e1701-ad54-42eb-8dc6-bbed77bc9b41 Version: $LATEST
>
> END RequestId: 9c8e1701-ad54-42eb-8dc6-bbed77bc9b41
>
> REPORT RequestId: 9c8e1701-ad54-42eb-8dc6-bbed77bc9b41    Duration:
>   517.98 ms Billed Duration: 600 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 93 MB

It can not upload file to ftp server. Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Please share the logs, esp. those with errors. Also just to be sure: Are you providing different parameters to the FTPClient constructor on lambda or is that as well trying to access `localhost`?

Comment: @michaelbahr Thank you for response. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide the error u come across.
Posibilities as below:

```
const handler = async (event) => {
   }
  module.exports = { handler }
```

.AWS lambda starts with aws handler function , hope you have included it in your aws lambda code
.how u r triggering the code. hope you provide value to event test configuration.

Comment: Manu Vargese it's only upload module file. My lambda function is run without any error. It can create csv file under 'tmp' folder but it can not upload.

Answer (score 0):

In short, FTP will not work with lambda since they use ephemeral ports.

Better to use SFTP or S3 will work nicely with lambda.